# Scraping with Selenium and BeautifulSoup: why are only the first 50 BeautifulSoup elements exported to CSV?

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

This is my first coding project and I am a complete newbie, apologies for any flaws in my question style.

I'm trying to scrape product details using Python, Selenium, BeautifulSoup. I am using Python 3.9, Firefox and Windows 10 for this.

What I want my program to do is open a webpage from a list of webpages, such as this webpage (I have a loop function that works):

https://uk.webuy.com/search/?categoryIds=1065&view=list&attributesData=eyJzZWxlY3RlZEF0dHJpYnV0ZUlkIjo5NSwiaXNBdHRyaWJ1dGVWYWx1ZUNoZWNrZWQiOjEsImF0dHJpYnV0ZXNEZXRhaWxzIjp7Ijk1IjpbIlRvc2hpYmEiXSwiMTQ0IjpbIldpbmRvd3MgMTAiXX19

General idea: the program opens a browser window, then keeps scrolling and clicking until it has reached the bottom and all product listings (e.g. 400 listings) are visible. It will then export some details to two CSV files: the descriptions (including title and prices), and an img tag. I will then format all this data in Excel.

Implementation: the program below opens a webpage, then waits until the 'show more results' button is visible, if there are enough products for such a button to become visible. It then reaches the bottom of the product listings by clicking this button on a while loop (this part works). It is also succesfully identifying and exporting the elements of the webpage to CSV files.

However, I am falling at the very last hurdle. The problem is that it is only exporting the first 50 elements to both CSV files. Incidentally (or not) this is the same number of elements that first appear on the page before the scrolling and clicking starts. However, it appears to be exporting the elements after all of the products have loaded.

Any help or suggestions as to how I can export the full page of elements would be much appreciated. And any suggestions for general improvements also welcome/appreciated as I'm sure this is poor code, since it's my first project, although it is mostly working for me.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

try:
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'showmoreresult')))
except TimeoutException:
    pass

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")

X = 0
while EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'showmoreresult')):
    element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@id='showmoreresult']")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    try:
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'showmoreresult')))
    except TimeoutException:
        X = 1
    if X == 1:
        break

records_list = soup.find_all("div", class_="desc")
print(records_list)

with open(r'C:\\directory\\details.csv', 'a', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for item in records_list:
        writer.writerow([item])
    writer.writerow(["New webpage"])
    f.close()

image_links = soup.find_all("div", class_="thumb")
print(image_links)

with open(r'C:\\directory\\image_urls.csv', 'a', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for item in image_links:
        writer.writerow([item])
    writer.writerow(["New webpage"])
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. I needed to move these down to after the while loop, once the page has loaded.

```
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")
```